# SWIG: reuse a selective exception handler?

Tags: c++, swig

I'm writing an %exception handler using SWIG. I'd like to use 2 different handlers: 1 for special cases, and another for everything else. Is there a way to do this? I.e., right now, I have this:

```
%exception {
   //basic error handling
}

%exception foo1 {
   //advanced error handling
}
%exception foo2 {
   //advanced error handling
}
%exception foo3 {
   //advanced error handling
}
```

but because all 3 foo handlers are the same (they're three members of the same class, if that helps), it would be nice for them to be the same code. It doesn't look like the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Customization.html#Customization_nn6) allows this. I don't think I can (or want) to use the advanced handler for everything because it's expensive and might not be threadsafe. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can always use SWIG macros:

```
%define %custom_exception
{ 
  //advanced error handling
}
%enddef
```

and then use

```
%exception foo1 %custom_exception
%exception foo2 %custom_exception
%exception foo3 %custom_exception
```